# Cucumber feature run report output is displaying in the console but not displaying in the html report

Tags: calabash-ios

```
Calabash-ios Version: >0.14.1 & RubyMine IDE
```

The below command produces the output in the console and the displayed output is not appearing in the html report.The report which shows only the feature file steps as attached.

```
Command1: DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 5s (8.1 Simulator)' cucumber features --format 'Calabash::Formatters::Html' --out index.html

Command2:DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 5s (8.1 Simulator)' cucumber features --format 'Slowhandcuke::Formatter' --format html --out realtrans2.html

Command3: DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 5s (8.1 Simulator)' cucumber features --format html --out reports1.html
```

Ex: Console Output

```
Mac:rt-mobile anupama$ DEVICE_TARGET='iPhone 5s (8.1 Simulator)' cucumber features --format 'Calabash::Formatters::Html' --out index.html

FARM AND HOME REAL ESTATE AND INSURANCE_17217 VENDOR COORDINATOR
Username from Database is: 'rustysun1'
Username from Database is: '100007187'
FARM AND HOME REAL ESTATE AND INSURANCE_17217 VENDOR PERFORMER
Username from Database is: 'rustysun1'
Username from Database is: '100007187'
DB User does not matches with the loggedin User
```

HTML Report: PFA report

gem list:

```
awesome_print (1.6.1)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.9.9, 1.9.6)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
calabash-common (0.0.1)
calabash-cucumber (0.14.2, 0.14.1)
CFPropertyList (2.3.1)
cucumber (1.3.19)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
edn (1.0.6)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
geocoder (1.2.8)
gherkin (2.12.2)
httpclient (2.6.0.1)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.2, 1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.11.0)
multi_test (0.1.2)
mysql (2.9.1)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.6.1)
rack-protection (1.5.3)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
retriable (2.0.2)
rspec (3.2.0)
rspec-core (3.2.3)
rspec-expectations (3.2.1)
rspec-mocks (3.2.1)
rspec-support (3.2.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
run_loop (1.3.3, 1.3.2)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sim_launcher (0.4.13)
sinatra (1.4.6)
slowhandcuke (0.0.3)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thor (0.19.1)
tilt (2.0.1)
tiny_tds (0.6.2)
version (1.0.0)
```

Comment: Feature file is running successfully but the console output is displaying in the console instead of displaying in the html report. It was working when calabash-cucumber -v 0.11.2 but not in 0.14.2. Please help me.

Comment: Puts text is not displaying in the html report